# Using a cloudforce.com login page for OAuth with a hybrid mobile app

Tags: mobile, oauth

Is it possible to use a cloudforce.com login page, e.g. https://example.cloudforce.com, to authenticate users with the PhoneGap OAuth plugin?

The plugin is called from javascript using:

```
PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "com.salesforce.oauth", "authenticate", [JSON.stringify(oauthProperties)]);
```

Passing the login domain in `oauthProperties` would seem to be the place to set it.  I found this changeset which removed `oauthLoginDomain` from `oauthProperties`: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/commit/2bb43033f2806cb5b827dd940c42eab09a7c3276

Is `oauthLoginDomain` still supported by the plugin, or is there a new way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited to reflect the fact that Salesforce Mobile SDK is in play**

The user can add a custom login host in the settings for their app (on iOS, from the home screen, Settings | *Your App* | Custom Host) and select it as the current login host.

So, the user can, in principle, add example.cloudforce.com as a custom host and select it for use. You can also add My Domain hostnames such as mycompany.my.salesforce.com - useful to have SAML work during the login.

I can't guarantee it will work with example.cloudforce.com in particular, but it certainly does work with dreamevent.my.salesforce.com - I've tried that login URL in the desktop Chatter app that uses the same OAuth flow.

Now, if you want to do all this without the user getting involved, it looks like you can edit shared/Classes/Security/SFAccountManager.m - lines 45, 46 in the current Mobile SDK for iOS:

```
// Value to use for login host if user never opens the app settings.
NSString * const kDefaultLoginHost = @"login.salesforce.com";
```

In the current Android version, lines 100, 101 of native/SalesforceSDK/src/com/salesforce/androidsdk/auth/OAuth2.java:

```
// Login URLs / paths
public static final String DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL = "https://login.salesforce.com";
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the Mobile SDK.  I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @xn. I've updated the answer to reflect your update.

Comment: do you know where I would need to make the change for the Android version of the Mobile SDK?

Comment: Edited the answer to add Android info

Comment: It works, but the branding doesn't appear on the OAuth login page.  For example, compare https://greatvines.cloudforce.com/?display=mobile and https://greatvines.cloudforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?display=mobile&response_type=token&client_id=3MVG9yZ.WNe6byQDn_tc_.9aCjokiSZgtfMc0rYyl2gijfWjNefSuy.JFCeJ0fz78nBxYgTz1KsRhEiWpWQup&scope=refresh_token%20api&redirect_uri=sfdc://success

Comment: Hmm - I'll see if I can figure out if it's possible to have the page branded correctly

Comment: Word from PM is "Looks like a bug - we'll look into it."

Comment: is there a way to get the bug listed at https://sites.secure.force.com/success/issues_index?

Comment: I've asked the PM - watch this space. Or that space...

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed. Thanks again, @metadata.